# Display a list of private products for unlogged users in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, private

For some reason, I need to show the list of private products on a single page on WooCommerce for guest users (non-logged in users). How can this be done with (or without) programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal woocommerce shortcode on a specific page where you want to display the private products, like for example:

```
[products limit="12" columns="4" paginate="true"]
```

You will set shortcode arguments as you wish *(like number of columns, number of items per page, enable pagination and so on)*…

Then to query all private products, use following *(replacing below `102` by the page ID where you are using the shortcode)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'display_private_product_list', 10, 3 );
function display_private_product_list( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ){
    if( get_the_id() == 102 ){
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
            $query_args['post_status'] = 'private';
        } else {
            $query_args['post_type'] = 'nothing'; // Display nothing for logged users
        }
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

It will display all private products for non logged users.

Comment: what's up with the `get_the_id() == 102` conditional?

Comment: @domdambrogia You will replace 102, by the page ID where you will add the shortcode

Comment: If I may add, could I know how to make a search form instead of just displaying the product list like using get_product_search_form filter? Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: @warnerque Sorry I don't catch… So yes you should open a new question if you like.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I mean could I allow someone to search on a text field for a product and then the results display the list of private products.